# List unique values using grouper

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe in which the index is a datetime and column A and B are objects. I need to see the unique values of A and B per week. 
I managed to get the unique value count per week (I am using the pd.grouper function for that) but I am struggling to get the unique values per week.

This code gives me the unique value counts per week

```
df_unique = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="W"))['A', 'B'].nunique())
```

However, the code below does not give me the unique values itself per week

```
df_unique_list = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="W"))['A', 'B'].unique())
```

This code gives me te following error message

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'unique'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use lambda function with [`Series.unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html) and converting to list:

```
np.random.seed(123)
rng = pd.date_range('2017-04-03', periods=20)
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.random.choice([1,2,3,4,5,6], size=20),
                   'B': np.random.choice([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], size=20)}, index=rng)  
print (df)
            A  B
2017-04-03  6  1
2017-04-04  3  5
2017-04-05  5  2
2017-04-06  3  8
2017-04-07  2  4
2017-04-08  4  3
2017-04-09  3  5
2017-04-10  4  8
2017-04-11  2  3
2017-04-12  2  5
2017-04-13  1  8
2017-04-14  2  1
2017-04-15  2  6
2017-04-16  1  1
2017-04-17  1  8
2017-04-18  2  2
2017-04-19  4  4
2017-04-20  6  5
2017-04-21  5  5
2017-04-22  1  5

df_unique_list = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="W"))['A', 'B'].agg(lambda x: list(x.unique()))
print (df_unique_list)
                          A                   B
2017-04-09  [6, 3, 5, 2, 4]  [1, 5, 2, 8, 4, 3]
2017-04-16        [4, 2, 1]     [8, 3, 5, 1, 6]
2017-04-23  [1, 2, 4, 6, 5]        [8, 2, 4, 5]
```

Comment: How could this dataframe be exported to a csv file while maintaining the list structure?

Comment: @JeroenSchuddebeurs - Unfortunately not, try  [`DataFrame.to_pickle`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_pickle.html), but pandas support not very nice lists in data.

Comment: @JeroenSchuddebeurs - Or maybe possible save to json.

Comment: converting it into JSON works fine for me since I can share the results with colleagues who can use their Notepad++.