# export dataframe to csv with columns containing lists

Tags: python-3.x

I have a dataframe containing columns with lists (each list has multiple DOBs) and an index as datetime (the lists are groups of values per 24 hours). Now, I would like to export the dataframe to a CSV but I get each DOB as a separate row. How can I keep the lists in the CSV export?

```py
df.to_csv(r'C:\\....\\df_list.csv', sep=';', index=True)
```

Comment: Can you also include a sample of your DataFrame? It would help to have a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) here where you describe your input, desired output, and how your current code is not behaving as expected.

Comment: Actually it is a follow up question on a previous question I had, which includes an example of my dataset. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57553554/list-unique-values-using-grouper